# Flash Slider misses numbers between 1 and 360.... why?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I've got the code below, but for some reason the Flash slider doesn't allow me to slide to some values (it's set between 1 and 360).

It goes something like `1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10`. The `snapInterval` is set to 1.

```
UIBox.addChild(speedSlider);

speedSlider.minimum = 1;
speedSlider.maximum = 360;
speedSlider.snapInterval = 1;
speedSlider.tickInterval = 45;
speedSlider.setSize(200, 50);
speedSlider.value = 13;
speedSlider.move(20, 80);
speedSlider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.THUMB_DRAG, updateSpeed);
```

Is there any way round this thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your width is set to 200 pixels:

```
speedSlider.setSize(200, 50);
```

You've also set the max value to be 360 — how can 360 different values be expressed using only 200 pixels? That's impossible, so some values will be non-selectable.